# Die if can't open file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a simple perl program to python that will append a journal entry to a text file. but I can't figure out how to make it die if it can't find the file.

Here is my perl code that works:

```
my $file = 'journal.txt'; #input destination
open my $fh, '>>', $file or die $!; #open file or kills it if error
```

I can open the file in python but nothing I have tried will kill it if it can't find it. This is what I have so far for the python:

```
with open('journal.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('input')
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "die"?

Comment: @Jason He is talking about perl's [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) command

Comment: You could use a `try/except` statement and print out an error when the file is not found.

Comment: 'a' will create the file if it doesn't exit and instead you want the program to error if it doesn't exist? I think you first have to try and read it, or first check to see if it exists (e.g. `os.path.isfile(fname)`)

Comment: It's far better to describe the behaviour you want than to provide code in another language. 1) The Python coders that could help may not know Perl, and 2) You might not need an exact duplicate of the Perl functionality. (e.g. What if Python's version produces a slightly different error message? Would that be acceptable or not?)

Comment: @idjaw *^she's talking about perl's die command

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the exception to raise something yourself or handle alternative logic in the except:

```
try:
    with open('some_file'):
        # logic
except IOError:
    # do things with your exception
```

Comment: This program doesn't die, it catches the exception and continues.

Comment: A raise can be used in the except.

Comment: Yes, but what is the point of catching the exception then reraising it? Also, this code doesn't work in python 2, and still doesn't directly die; instead it does some things and then possible dies.

Comment: I just ran it on Python 2.7.6. Works.

Answer (score 3):

The code that you have will work, i.e. the Python process will "die" if it fails to open the file.

If the file can not be opened, e.g. due to insufficient permissions, an exception will be raised. That exception is not caught so it will propagate to the top level, and the Python interpreter will eventually terminate of it its own accord.

However, it will not behave exactly the same as the perl version, e.g. the exit code and error message will vary. You want a controlled exit from the Python process and to set an appropriate exit code. You can do that by catching the exception and accessing the error message and error code. A little more work by digging into the traceback provides the line number and file name, and you can then produce output that more closely resembles that of perl.

```
import sys

try:
    with open('journal.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('input')
except IOError as exc:    # Python 2. For Python 3 use OSError
    tb = sys.exc_info()[-1]
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
    print('{} at {} line {}.'.format(exc.strerror, filename, lineno))
    sys.exit(exc.errno)
```

For comparison perl produces this when it can't open the output file:

```
$ perl x.pl
Permission denied at x.pl line 2.
$ echo $?
13
```

and the above Python script produces this:

```
$ python x.py
Permission denied at x.py line 4.
$ echo $?
13
```

Answer (score 2):

You code already does that, as the `open('journal.txt', 'a')` call will throw and `IOError` (`OSError` in python 3) if it fails to open the file. If your program does not catch that error, it will eventually propogate to the top of the stack and exit the interpreter after printing a traceback.

Comment: Worth noting that it will create the file if it doesn't exist though, so this will only fail if creation fails (eg due to directory write permissions)

Comment: Or the file exists and is not writable.